# Predicting using an exponential model

Tags: r, lm

I have the following data:

```
Days    Total cases
1   3
2   3
3   5
4   6
5   28
6   30
7   31
8   34
9   39
10  48
11  63
12  70
13  82
14  91
15  107
16  112
17  127
18  146
19  171
20  198
21  258
22  334
23  403
24  497
25  571
26  657
27  730
28  883
29  1024
30  1139
31  1329
32  1635
33  2059
34  2545
35  3105
36  3684
37  4289
38  4778
39  5351
40  5916
41  6729
42  7600
43  8452
44  9210
45  10453
46  11484
47  12370
48  13431
49  14353
50  15724
51  17304
52  18543
53  20080
54  21372
```

I defined days as 'days' and total cases as 'cases1'. I run the following code:

```
exp.mod <- lm(log(cases1)~days)
```

I get a good model with reasonable residuals and p-value.

but when i run the following:

```
predict(exp.mod, data.frame(days=60))
```

I get the value of 11.66476, which doesnt seem to be correct.

I need to get the value and also include the predictive plot in the exponential model.
Hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: did you ty `predict(exp.mod, 46)` ?

Comment: I tried predict(exp.mod, data.frame(days1=46)) but it gives me wrong values.... the above code gives an error - Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : not that many frames on the stack

Comment: What are the types of `df1` and `days1`: both vectors ? That's weird to call a vector `df1`

Comment: yes both are vectors. I was in hurry while doing this so just put any name. Could it cause a problem?

Comment: @Ojaswita; can we have a reproducible example please; your code `predict(exp.mod, data.frame(days1=46))` *should* work in principle but it is often easier to pass a dataframe to `lm` and use the `data=` arguments rather than variables from the global environment.

Comment: @Ojaswita; can you also explain your comment above please; does your predict call "*give the wrong values*" or does it "*give an error*"

Comment: If you use a `data.frame` to predict, you should use one to construct lm object. I would first try: `reg <- lm(I(log(y))~days1, data = df)` and `predict(reg, data.frame(days1 = 46))`

Comment: By the way, if you use `log`, you should put that into a `I()` element to get `R` interpret the math

Comment: @linog ; `log` does not need to be wrapped in `I`

Comment: Ok my bad, I thought it needed

Comment: @user20650 i get a wrong answer, not an error. Should I post the entire code and/or dataset?

Comment: @Ojaswita; if you can post enough of the data and code to reproduce the output that you are concerned about, and explain why you think the predict call gives the wrong answer please.

Comment: @user20650, I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: thanks for the update @Ojaswita. Why do you not think that the prediction is reasonable -- do remember that it is on the log scale. I read your data into a dataframe called `dat`, and then ran your regression. I then plot the data and overlaid the regression line. Here is the code `with(dat, plot(Days, log(Total_cases), xlim=c(0,60), ylim=c(0,12))); abline(exp.mod)`. So a prediction of `11.66` is somewhat reasonable....

Comment: ... cont... That said, the plot of the data does seem to show a bit of a lowering of the slope towards 50, perhaps indicating that it may not be sensible to assume the same association when extrapolating beyond the range of your data.

Comment: Thank you very much @user20650, please can you put your details as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you should consider the `EST` models from the `forecast` package.

Below an example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
ausair %>% ets() %>% forecast() %>% autoplot()
```

I suggest you to check the free [book](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ets-forecasting.html) of the  Prof. Rob J Hyndman and Prof George Athanasopoulos wrote (are the authors of the forecast package).